# Using commands in the Data Model scope

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

In my program I am trying to write commands for a User Control that will toggle the `isEnabled` and `isChecked` property of a few controls. Attached to my User Control is a View Model and a Data Model. My commands and properties are in my Data Model (First of all, is this correct implementation?), and there is a property for my Data Model inside my View Model.

The commands are not working. I do not get any binding errors, and when I debug my code, the values are changed correctly. However, there is no visual feedback.

My View Model is set as the `DataContext` of the User Control in it's constructor.

My data is bound like this:

```
<CheckBox Command="{Binding Model.myCommand}" ... />
```

This is an example of what one of my commands looks like:

```
public Command myCommand { get { return _myCommand; } }
private void MyCommand_C()
{
       if (_myCommand== true) //Checked
       {
           _checkBoxEnabled = true;
       }
       else //UnChecked
       {
           _checkBoxEnabled = false;
           _checkBox = false;
       }
}
```

Why aren't these commands functioning?

Comment: You are using commands in a completely wrong manner.

Comment: for starters, you bind it to `myCommand` while the name of it in the model is `MyCommand_C`

Comment: Please show me how to do it correctly. I should bind it to `Model.MyCommand_C`?

Comment: Please read this:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM.

Comment: Should I even use commands to do these actions?

Comment: Your need is very basic, and have tons of approches in MVVM. A common belief is to have the command lie in your `ViewModel`, have the `IsEnabled` and `IsChecked` of your controls in the view be binded to properties in your `ViewModel` implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and in the command execution toggle those properties. See my answer below for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Commands` should be implemented in the `ViewModel`.

There or in your Models, you should have Properties binded to the `IsChecked` and `IsEnabled` properties of your controls, and in the command, changing the properties will trigger `PropertyChanged` event which will update your views.

Example:

In your view :

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}"/>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Model.IsChecked}"/>
        <CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Model.IsEnabled}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Model = new MyModel();

        ToggleCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
            {
                Model.IsChecked = !Model.IsChecked;
                Model.IsEnabled = !Model.IsEnabled;
            });
    }

    public DelegateCommand ToggleCommand { get; set; }

    public MyModel Model { get; set; }
}
```

Model:

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isChecked;
    private bool _isEnabled;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return _isChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
        }
    }

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _isEnabled;
        }
        set
        {
            _isEnabled = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsEnabled"));
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I use Prism framework, hence the `DelegateCommand` and `RaisePropertyChanged` lambda expression, but this concept is very basic in MVVM, and can be done in any MVVM framework.

Comment: That all makes sense, but if I move all of my properties over to my ViewModel, what is the point of my Data Model?

Comment: @Ericafterdark Updated my answer accordinly to your comment. Hope this makes things more clear

Comment: @Ericafterdark you don't have to move any properties to your `ViewModel`. You can bind directly to them using a `Path` in the bindings ...

Answer (score 0):

First, your `Command` properties should be in your ViewModel, not your data model.

Setting that aside, you should not bind a `CheckBox` to a `Command` - commands are for elements that trigger actions (such as clicking a `Button`).  A `CheckBox` should be bound to a `bool` property.  Where the property should reside can be debated, but my opinion is that it should be in the ViewModel so you can keep the Property Changed Notification logic out of your data model.

A quick example:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _myCheckValue;
    public bool MyCheckValue
    {
        get { return _myCheckValue; }
        set 
        {
            _myCheckValue = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyCheckValue");
        }
    }

    //INotifyPropertyChange implementation not included...
}
```

And then in your XAML (assuming the ViewModel is the DataContext):

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MyCheckValue}" ... />
```